# How to hide git tooltip in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image]

Git related tooltip is showing permanently in my vscode, especially in markdown files.
In other files such as css, it is only showing when I click on the line, which is not a problem.

How do I turn it off?

Comment: It might be one of your vs code extensions, Just find and uninstall it (Could be `git lens`)

Comment: disable `CodeLens` in extension, search all settings

Comment: Adding the following in settings.json was a more solid solution:

`"gitlens.codeLens.authors.enabled": false`
`"gitlens.codeLens.recentChange.enabled": false`

Had to reinstall/enable gitlens again and found my way around to solve the issue better.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the GitLens extension.

Use the `> GitLens: Open Settings` command (Ctrl + Shift + P on Win/Linux, Cmd + Shift + P on Mac) to configure it's behaviour. `Git CodeLens` setting is the one that's adding the author to the top of the code blocks.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't really figure how to specify settings for each file extension. so I simply uninstalled it.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** What solved my issue was to add to the settings json file the following lines:

```
"gitlens.codeLens.authors.enabled": false,
"gitlens.codeLens.recentChange.enabled": false
```

---

Before the change:
[image]

After the change:
[image]

---

I wanted to make visible what [@jesvtb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11749892/jesvtb) was mentioning in the comments, because that's the actual solution

Answer (score 1):

Additional to what previous posters mentioned, in my case, I also had to disable current line inline blame, besides the other two.

[image]

```
"gitlens.currentLine.enabled": false
```